# <body> width & height

Tags: html

I have a background image repeating in a div after the body tag. 
I gave both body and div a width and height of 100% because even if there is not enough content to show I want that image to show on the entire browser.

And this works if there is not scrollbars on the page, if there is many content showing and I need to scroll down the background image gets broken and after that is white.

Any help?

Comment: Is there any reason not to attach the background to `<body>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[`background-attachment:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-attachment) will keep your background at a fixed position, so that the background does not disappear when you scroll down.

### Update:

In your case, the background is *not* attached to `<body>`, but two nested child elements. I propose two possible solutions:

#### Method 1: Without changing HTML

Current document structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainbg">
        <div id="bg">
```

Suggested CSS for this:

```
html, body { margin:0;padding:0; } /*Included in answer, because it's important*/
#mainbg {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#bg {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

#### Method 2: Recommended solution:

Move the background (image) property to the `<body>` element, and remove `<div id="mainbg">`.

```
<body>
    <div id="bg">
```

CSS:

```
html, body { margin:0;padding:0; }
body {
    background: url(../images/main-bg-pat.png) 0 0;
}
#bg {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add `position: fixed` for older browsers not supporting CSS3. But your code is needed for mobile browsers not supporting my code.

Comment: @Yogu [All (modern) browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html) (excluding IE6-) support this property.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro Can you show your page where it "does not work"? Is another element hiding your image?

Comment: i´m working in localhost. no, that is not the case I think, because when I open firebug in mozilla and mouseover the body tag, the body tag itself ends when the background image ends. And everything else after is white and content is still there

Comment: Did you place `background-attachment` **after** the declaration of `background:....url(...)`? If you place `background:...url(...)...;` after `background-attachment`, the property will be overwritten. Have a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background) if you want to combine multiple `background` properties in a short-property.

Comment: i´ll put online so you can see if its ok

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro That background is not attached to `<body>`. See my updated answer: Replace `height:100%;` with `min-height:100%;`.

Comment: does not work also. that solves the problem when there´s lot of content and i need to scroll down. But when I open a page that has small info and does not fill the entire browser window, the background gets cut again to the size of the content. I don´t understand, if it is the first div after the body element, it should work I think.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro Add `overflow:auto;` at `#mainbg`, and replace `height` at `#bg` with `min-height`.

Comment: I added min-height:auto and height:100% and now everything works great. Thank you

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro I have updated my answer with another solution, which I **recommend**, because it's more cleaner.