# How do I repeat a background-image for the whole page?

Tags: css

On this [link](http://macoverflow.org/) you can see that the page has a background image, but when you scroll, the background image does not repeat down the page.

How do I write the CSS so that the background-image covers the whole page (if the content does not fill one window), but continues down through the page if it is larger than one window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<body> width & height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771018/body-width-height). If you want to add additional information to a question **edit it**, don't start a new one.

Comment: I don't think this user understands how this site works, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the css height off the class mainbg, setting the body to 100% and setting a child div to 100% height will make its height essentially the height of the browser viewport

Comment: I´m not sure I understand what you mean here. What I do with class mainbg?

Comment: I meant to say that i don´t understand what you said before. if I put the height to 100% it does not work with small content pages! =(

Comment: set min-height:100% (this makes it so if u have less content then the size of the viewport it will expand to that size, and height:auto, or remove it

Comment: I did the reverse and it works great. min-height: auto and height: 100%. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should change the bg `height:100%;` to `height:auto;`.

Comment: that does not work 100% in my case. I´ll explain.

Comment: why not? I'm doing that in developer tools & it seem to work?

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro I found mine works. You just have two different id's and they're messing things up.

Comment: sorry for previous comment. That does not work 100% for me. If I use height: 100% it will always use the entire browser window as long I don´t need to scroll. If I do like you say height: auto, then if I have a empty page or only one small paragraph then the bg image will NOT in my case use the entire browser window wich I want that. But it does fix the scroll as long as it have lots of content in it.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro Who are you talking to?

Comment: If so you should also add min-height:100%;

Comment: yes! check here http://macoverflow.org/?p=37 does not show in full browser, theres that uggly white space. But, if you click home everything is fine.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro the reverse should work! height:100% min-height:auto; let me know!

Comment: And it does indeed! Everything is nice now. Thank you very much for all the help here. =)